# downloading multiple files from google drive in one go

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, google-drive, download-manager, file-download

I want to download multiple files from google drive please see the following link
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0ByWO0aO1eI_MN1BEd3VNRUZENkU?fbclid=IwAR0IO8fiSdYTsQvhuX890KbqadpKHJ4oshcvQcHgNK2WTTK5Bn94mXoOMkQ
is there any utility by which I can download multiple files multiple folders all at the same time from google drive.

Answer (score 0):

You can mark multiple files by holding `ctrl`. Then right-click and select download. This will trigger Chrome to ask you if Google Drive can download multiple files. If you allow it, this can work without any additional utilities.

Answer (score 0):

Just to update this:  Google Drive File Stream is a faster and more reliable method than downloading through the browser.  It has become part of the desktop Google Drive client [("Download Drive for Desktop")](https://www.google.com/drive/download/).

Instead of using the old-school method of syncing everything, you can choose the method which shows your Drive as a mounted Drive Letter, and you can copy from it as if it's a local or network drive (just limited by your internet speed).

If the files are in a folder you don't own, you can click the folder drop-down in the Drive WebUI and add a shortcut to your Drive, so that you can access it via the desktop Drive program.

The reason it's overall better than the WebUI is that especially for either lots of files, or large files, it handles internet interruptions without a problem, as it does all the work in the background, whereas a Drive WebUI download can easily be interrupted, then you have to start over.